# odbc results inaccurate (odbc + iis8.5 + asp classic)

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

Apologizes for my poor English.

i have an asp classic app on iis8.5 (window server 2012).
the app uses access odbc connection with DSN connect to local mdb file.

===========================

```
product_price table records :

productcode | productprice

pc001 | 4.1

pc002 | 10.55

pc003 | 8.4
```

===========================

ASP code :

```
DSNprw = "DSN=TEMP_PRICE";

Connprw = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");

Connprw.Open(DSNprw); 

sqlq = "select * from product_price";

quo_pt = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet");

quo_pt.Open (sqlq, Connprw);

while (! (quo_pt.EOF)) 

{

// loop to dispay records from resultset

Response.Write(quo_pt.fields.item("productcode") );

Response.Write("<br/>" );

Response.Write(quo_pt.fields.item("productprice") );


}
```

===========================

the result display on webpage :

```
pc001

4.09

pc002

10.54

pc003

8.40
```

===========================

tested using same table records on firebird with same asp code,

result display inaccurate as access

Any ideas ?

## UPDATE 29 Nov 2014

Tested with [ODBC Test tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712676(v=vs.85).aspx) from micosoft, the odbc return accurate query resultsets.
Then it should be something go wrong with the iis8.5 or the classic asp.

Comment: thanks @ScottJShea for code format

Comment: how is it inaccurate ? The value is totally different  or difference in format ? maybe you could show the values in the db ?

Comment: inaccurate in decimal value. for example 4.1 become as 4.09

Comment: actual values in database are 4.1, 10.55, and 8.4 . but the results display on webpage are 4.09, 10.54 and 8.4 . any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be that when you're looking at your table in Access you have some setting which rounds to the closest 0.05, while your webpage is giving the actual data?

Comment: @John checked access database, doesn't have any relevant setting